# Gem install not finding existing gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, boilerpipe

When running gem install I get the following:

```
gregoryostermayr@gregors test $ gem install jruby-boilerpipe
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jruby-boilerpipe' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: boilerpipe, jruby-coercion, jruby_coercion
```

If I create a Gemfile and use bundler to install everything works as normal:

```
gregoryostermayr@gregors test $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Installing jruby-boilerpipe 0.2.0.rc2
```

Network access doesn't seem to be an issue - trying from an MRI ruby installation results in the same. Anyone else ever see this?

Comment: Does `gem install jruby-boilerpipe --pre` work? Do you specify a version in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: This is exactly what is going on - the only versions published have rc versions. Submit this as an answer Matt and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only versions of that gem currently available are [“prerelease” gems](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#version), as the versions all end in `rc1` or `rc2`.

To install it, use the `--prerelease` option to `install` (you can shorten this to just `--pre`:

```
$ gem intstall jruby-boilerpipe --pre
```

It appears that Bundler automatically installs prerelease gems if they are the only ones available.